# How to change the third character of a list cell

Tags: c#, list, visual-studio, bindingsource

I can change the whole list cell as one, but I couldn't figure out how to change just the third character of a cell.

These two don't work:

```
list[index].CELL_A.Substring(2,1) = 'd';

list[index].CELL_A.ElementAtOrDefault(2) = 'd'
```

But this, where you save the whole cell, works:

```
liste[index].CELL_A = "Text";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `StringBuilder` to solve your problem (or also a `charArray`) I'll give the solution with a `StringBuilder`...

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(list[index]);
sb[2] = 's';
list[index] = sb.ToString();
```

...or with an `Array of Chars`:

```
char[] charArr = list[index].ToCharArray();
charArr[2] = 's';
list[index] = new string(charArr);
```

You can't directly modify a **string** object, because they're **immutable objects**.
In fact, in both solution case I've shown you the `list[index]` element will point to a new modified string object and you'll "lose" the old string (list[index] will point to a new memory cell containing the new modified value).